# how to batch delete redis keys in one command

Tags: redis

Now I am connect to redis, find some keys like this:

```
> keys "user:login:user:*"
user:login:user:62668
user:login:user:61970
user:login:user:63586

......
```

Now I want to delete this keys, I have tried:

```
keys "user:login:user:*" | xargs del

keys "user:login:user:*" | del

keys "user:login:user:*" | redis-cli xargs del
```

both could not work, what should I do to delete it batch for one action?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61366419/how-to-atomically-delete-millions-of-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-pure-redis/61366420#61366420

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Better way

Although @Guy Korland answered the question, but that way may cause long-term blocking. We should always remmber redis use single thread to operate data, so if you have a lot of keys match `user:login:user:*` or each key's type is `list`, `set`, `hash`, `sorted_set` with a lot of elements. The deletion process will cost lots of time, redis cannot respond to other command.

```sh
redis-cli --scan --pattern users:* | xargs redis-cli unlink
```

use `scan` && `unlink` instead of `keys` && `del` can avoid blocking.

#### For the difference between `scan` and `keys`, `unlink` and `del`:

[scan vs keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603964/scan-vs-keys-performance-in-redis)
[del vs unlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818371/is-the-unlink-command-always-better-than-del-command)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `redis-cli` with --raw to get the result clean as arguments fro the `redis-cli del`

```sh
redis-cli del `redis-cli --raw keys "user:login:user:*"`
```